# Insert on duplicate key update didn't update, instead insert new value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table with 4 row, 1 Primary key with auto-increment , the row is check_id..

What I want to do is *insert a new data if no data exist and update data based on id if it exist.*

I already use:

```
insert into checklist (check_pos,check_ok,check_code) values ('$names','$names','$code')  on duplicate key update check_ok = '$names'
```

But this only insert a new value.

Instead, I tried to change the `check_id` to *unique key* and it also the same,

Is there something wrong with my update query or my table?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$ew = mysql_query("select * from pos_unit where pos_unit_name like '%Director%'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($ew);
while($eq = mysql_fetch_array($ew))
{
$pos = $eq['pos_unit_name'];
$checklist = mysql_query("select * from checklist where check_ok = '$pos'");
$excheck = mysql_fetch_array($checklist);
$poss = $excheck['check_pos'];
?>
<li>
<div class="form_grid_12">
<label class="field_title" id="actual"><?php echo $eq['pos_unit_name']; ?></label>
<div class="form_input">
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $excheck['check_id']; ?>">
<input name="position[]" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php if($pos == $poss) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> value="<?php echo $eq['pos_unit_name']; ?>" style="opacity: 0;">
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

and this is the php code..

```
include 'config.php';


$code = $_POST['code'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
//$dist = $_POST['selectdistarg'];
$check = $_POST['position'];
//$input = $_POST['selectinp'];
//$eval = $_POST['selecteval'];


foreach($check as $index => $names)
{               
    $up = mysql_query("insert into checklist (check_pos,check_ok,check_code) values ('$names','$names','$code') on duplicate key update check_ok = '$names'") or die (mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: You need a unique key/index/constraint on the table.  What columns are unique?

Comment: what do you insert to check_id?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i tried to change the check_id to unique , but its no help..

Comment: @RonaldAlexanderKailola its an auto-increment , so `INT` .

Comment: nah its because auto increment.. when you insert the record check id is increment by 1 and you never have the same unique id.. so the record became insert not update

Answer (score 1):

The database is performing as expected.

Each time you `INSERT` a new record you are getting a new, autonumbered value in `check_id`.  Because this is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table and because you do not have any other `UNIQUE INDEX`es declared, there is never a duplicate key situation encountered.

To get the behavior you want, you must declare and additional `UNIQUE INDEX` including the columns that make each row truly unique.  Once you've done that, you could consider eliminating `check_id` and promoting the `UNIQUE INDEX` to be the table's `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: which mean i have to add a new row to make it unique ?

Comment: No, you must create a new *index* listing the columns that have to be unique to allow a new row to be added.  Then, when you add a row that violates that index, the `duplicate key` clause will be invoked.  You cannot use `check_id` for this job because it *always* gets a new value for every row.

Comment: well , i tried to change the `check_code` to `UNIQUE` , it said, "Duplicate Entry for 'F001' key 'check_code'...